# Setting up Airflow with Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, airflow

I am trying to setup Airflow via Docker on AWS EC2 Linux 2. I am referencing this blog: https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-apache-airflow-2-with-docker-e5b974b37728
.

I have changed the environment variable files by changing IP, db password and admin credentials (view file path setup below)

[image]

And I ran:
sudo docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yaml airflow

But I get the following error:

```
    Updating service airflow_server (id: gat4to...)
image airflow2-docker:1.0.0 could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access airflow2-docker:1.0.0 independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different
versions of the image.
```

After researching online, I am not clear as to what exactly a next step would be to solve this.

Comment: That looks like a warning, not an error

Comment: right, but airlfow did not spin up, and I do not have a clear indication as to why